# disable route being added to camel context based on some condition

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi

I need to restrict particular routes being added to the camel context based on some condition. Tried RoutePolicy.onStart -> but this method is being invoked after starting the route.

I need a way to to completely avoid the route being generated/added to camel context.

```
 private List<String> eligibleRoutes;

 @Override
  public void onStart(Route route) {
    LOGGER.info("onInit for {}", route.getId());
    if (isCollectionNotEmpty(eligibleRoutes))
    {
      LOGGER.info("route-start eligibility for route {}", route.getId());
      if (eligibleRoutes.contains(route.getId()))
      {
        LOGGER.info("Route-start is set to ELIGiBLE for {}", route.getId());
      }else{
        LOGGER.info("Route-start is set to NOT ELIGiBLE for {}", route.getId());

        route.getRouteContext().getCamelContext().stopRoute(route.getId());
        boolean status = route.getRouteContext().getCamelContext().removeRoute(route.getId());
        return;
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring integration or creating and managing the `CamelContext` yourself? How's the route added to the context in your code?

Comment: Using blueprint to create camelContext and routes. I have multiple routes and need to make them visible only when it is eligible.

Comment: How about [Content Based Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the route to autoStartup=false, and then in the `onInit` method you can determine if it should be started anyway, and call its startRoute method.

Or another way is to configure CamelContext to have `autoStartup=false`, and then you can have an Camel event lister bean that listen for `CamelContextStartedEvent`, and then you trigger there to find out which routes you want to start, and call the `camelContext.startRoute("nameOfRoute")`.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I tried EventNotifierSupport with CamelContextStartedEvent and it worked like a charm.